# Stylesheet to change elment's name

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML

```
<ExternalAssessmentRequest>

</ExternalAssessmentRequest>
```

Really appreciate your help if anyone can help me.
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XSLT 1.0 version of the answer, without addressing the namespace issues discussed with other answers.  The simplified assumption is that the list of old and new names does not change namespace prefixes and uses the same namespace prefixes as the input source file.

```
t:\ftemp>type plural.xml 
<ExternalAssessmentRequest>
    <ApplicationData Lender="MegaBank">
        <LiabilityList>
            <RequestedLoans>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
                <Features Code="Test"/>
            </RequestedLoans>
            <ExistingLoans>
                <Securities RelatedIdentifier="Test"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </ExistingLoans>
            <OtherLiabilities >
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </OtherLiabilities>
            <Expenses Amount="50" Description="Train Ticket" Identifier="Expense1" NonRecurring="Yes" Type="Transport" Year="2013">
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </Expenses>
        </LiabilityList>
        <AssetList>
            <Assets >
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </Assets>
            <Funds Amount="1000" Description="Slush Fund" Identifier="Fund1"/>
        </AssetList>
        <IncomeList>
            <Incomes >
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </Incomes>
        </IncomeList>
        <ApplicantList>
            <Households AdditionalAdults="0" Boarding="Yes" Children="0" Description="1 Test St, Sydney" Postcode="2000">
                <Persons CountryOfResidence="Australia" CustomerDurationInMonths="0" DischargedBankrupts="0" Identifier="Applicant1" Name="John Smith" Partner="Applicant2" Partnered="Yes" PermanentResident="Yes"/>
                <Persons CountryOfResidence="Australia" CustomerDurationInMonths="0" DischargedBankrupts="0" Identifier="Applicant2" Name="Jane Smith" Partner="Applicant1" Partnered="Yes" PermanentResident="Yes"/>
                <Guarantors/>
            </Households>
            <Companies Identifier="Company1" Name="Tardis">
                <Directors RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
            </Companies>
        </ApplicantList>
        <FeeList>
            <Fees Amount="100" Capitalised="Yes" DateOfPayment="1967-08-13" Description="Application Fee" Identifier="Fee1" PaidAmount="0"/>
        </FeeList>
    </ApplicationData>
    <AdditionalAssessments Lender="MegaBank">
        <RequestedLoans Product="Supa Variable" ProductID="Product2"/>
    </AdditionalAssessments>
</ExternalAssessmentRequest>
t:\ftemp>call xslt plural.xml plural.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ExternalAssessmentRequest>
    <ApplicationData Lender="MegaBank">
        <LiabilityList>
            <RequestedLoan>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
                <Features Code="Test"/>
            </RequestedLoan>
            <ExistingLoans>
                <Securities RelatedIdentifier="Test"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </ExistingLoans>
            <OtherLiabilities>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </OtherLiabilities>
            <Expenses Amount="50" Description="Train Ticket" Identifier="Expense1" NonRecurring="Yes" Type="Transport" Year="2013">
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </Expenses>
        </LiabilityList>
        <AssetList>
            <Assets>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </Assets>
            <Funds Amount="1000" Description="Slush Fund" Identifier="Fund1"/>
        </AssetList>
        <IncomeList>
            <Incomes>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </Incomes>
        </IncomeList>
        <ApplicantList>
            <Households AdditionalAdults="0" Boarding="Yes" Children="0" Description="1 Test St, Sydney" Postcode="2000">
                <Persons CountryOfResidence="Australia" CustomerDurationInMonths="0" DischargedBankrupts="0" Identifier="Applicant1" Name="John Smith" Partner="Applicant2" Partnered="Yes" PermanentResident="Yes"/>
                <Persons CountryOfResidence="Australia" CustomerDurationInMonths="0" DischargedBankrupts="0" Identifier="Applicant2" Name="Jane Smith" Partner="Applicant1" Partnered="Yes" PermanentResident="Yes"/>
                <Guarantors/>
            </Households>
            <Company Identifier="Company1" Name="Tardis">
                <Directors RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
            </Company>
        </ApplicantList>
        <FeeList>
            <Fees Amount="100" Capitalised="Yes" DateOfPayment="1967-08-13" Description="Application Fee" Identifier="Fee1" PaidAmount="0"/>
        </FeeList>
    </ApplicationData>
    <AdditionalAssessments Lender="MegaBank">
        <RequestedLoan Product="Supa Variable" ProductID="Product2"/>
    </AdditionalAssessments>
</ExternalAssessmentRequest>
t:\ftemp>type plural.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:data="urn:X-data"
                exclude-result-prefixes="data"
                version="1.0">

<data:convert>
  <convert old="RequestedLoans" new="RequestedLoan"/>
  <convert old="Companies" new="Company"/>
  ...add more here...
</data:convert>

<xsl:key name="converts" match="convert" use="@old"/>

<xsl:template match="*[name(.)=document('')/*/data:convert/convert/@old]">
  <xsl:variable name="here" select="."/>
  <xsl:for-each select="document('')">
    <xsl:element name="{key('converts',name($here))/@new}"
                 namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$here/@*|$here/node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!--identity for all other nodes-->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
t:\ftemp>rem Done!
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with a look-up table that you can fill in yourself:

```
t:\ftemp>type plural.xml 
<ExternalAssessmentRequest>
    <ApplicationData Lender="MegaBank">
        <LiabilityList>
            <RequestedLoans>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
                <Features Code="Test"/>
            </RequestedLoans>
            <ExistingLoans>
                <Securities RelatedIdentifier="Test"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </ExistingLoans>
            <OtherLiabilities >
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </OtherLiabilities>
            <Expenses Amount="50" Description="Train Ticket" Identifier="Expense1" NonRecurring="Yes" Type="Transport" Year="2013">
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </Expenses>
        </LiabilityList>
        <AssetList>
            <Assets >
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </Assets>
            <Funds Amount="1000" Description="Slush Fund" Identifier="Fund1"/>
        </AssetList>
        <IncomeList>
            <Incomes >
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </Incomes>
        </IncomeList>
        <ApplicantList>
            <Households AdditionalAdults="0" Boarding="Yes" Children="0" Description="1 Test St, Sydney" Postcode="2000">
                <Persons CountryOfResidence="Australia" CustomerDurationInMonths="0" DischargedBankrupts="0" Identifier="Applicant1" Name="John Smith" Partner="Applicant2" Partnered="Yes" PermanentResident="Yes"/>
                <Persons CountryOfResidence="Australia" CustomerDurationInMonths="0" DischargedBankrupts="0" Identifier="Applicant2" Name="Jane Smith" Partner="Applicant1" Partnered="Yes" PermanentResident="Yes"/>
                <Guarantors/>
            </Households>
            <Companies Identifier="Company1" Name="Tardis">
                <Directors RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
            </Companies>
        </ApplicantList>
        <FeeList>
            <Fees Amount="100" Capitalised="Yes" DateOfPayment="1967-08-13" Description="Application Fee" Identifier="Fee1" PaidAmount="0"/>
        </FeeList>
    </ApplicationData>
    <AdditionalAssessments Lender="MegaBank">
        <RequestedLoans Product="Supa Variable" ProductID="Product2"/>
    </AdditionalAssessments>
</ExternalAssessmentRequest>
t:\ftemp>call xslt2 plural.xml plural.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ExternalAssessmentRequest>
    <ApplicationData Lender="MegaBank">
        <LiabilityList>
            <RequestedLoan>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
                <Features Code="Test"/>
            </RequestedLoan>
            <ExistingLoans>
                <Securities RelatedIdentifier="Test"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </ExistingLoans>
            <OtherLiabilities>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </OtherLiabilities>
            <Expenses Amount="50" Description="Train Ticket" Identifier="Expense1" NonRecurring="Yes" Type="Transport" Year="2013">
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </Expenses>
        </LiabilityList>
        <AssetList>
            <Assets>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </Assets>
            <Funds Amount="1000" Description="Slush Fund" Identifier="Fund1"/>
        </AssetList>
        <IncomeList>
            <Incomes>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </Incomes>
        </IncomeList>
        <ApplicantList>
            <Households AdditionalAdults="0" Boarding="Yes" Children="0" Description="1 Test St, Sydney" Postcode="2000">
                <Persons CountryOfResidence="Australia" CustomerDurationInMonths="0" DischargedBankrupts="0" Identifier="Applicant1" Name="John Smith" Partner="Applicant2" Partnered="Yes" PermanentResident="Yes"/>
                <Persons CountryOfResidence="Australia" CustomerDurationInMonths="0" DischargedBankrupts="0" Identifier="Applicant2" Name="Jane Smith" Partner="Applicant1" Partnered="Yes" PermanentResident="Yes"/>
                <Guarantors/>
            </Households>
            <Company Identifier="Company1" Name="Tardis">
                <Directors RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
            </Company>
        </ApplicantList>
        <FeeList>
            <Fees Amount="100" Capitalised="Yes" DateOfPayment="1967-08-13" Description="Application Fee" Identifier="Fee1" PaidAmount="0"/>
        </FeeList>
    </ApplicationData>
    <AdditionalAssessments Lender="MegaBank">
        <RequestedLoan Product="Supa Variable" ProductID="Product2"/>
    </AdditionalAssessments>
</ExternalAssessmentRequest>
t:\ftemp>type plural.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:data="urn:X-data"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsd data"
                version="2.0">

<data:convert>
  <convert old="RequestedLoans" new="RequestedLoan"/>
  <convert old="Companies" new="Company"/>
  ...add more here...
</data:convert>

<xsl:key name="converts" match="convert" use="@old"/>

<xsl:template match="*[key('converts',name(.),document(''))]">
  <xsl:element name="{key('converts',name(.),document(''))/@new}"
               namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*,node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!--identity for all other nodes-->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*,node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
t:\ftemp>rem Done!
```

Edited to ensure namespace preservation in a general solution, not assuming the elements are in no namespace.  Thanks to Mads for doing this first in his posted solution.

Comment: Mads, I disagree with your edit changing `name(.)` to `local-name(.)`.  Consider if an element has a prefix 'x:' in both the old and new names, then `x:` is going to be needed in the result name.  A truly namespace-aware transliteration would be keyed on namespace name and not namespace prefix.  I suggest that the original code be restored because your code is going to shave off all prefixes and use the default namespace for all elements.

Comment: My edit was just for the key lookup values. Otherwise, you would need to include the prefix in the `@old` mapping value, right? It still has `@namespace` on the `xsl:element`, so the generated element would still have the namespace. It might not retain the namespace-prefix, but wouldn't that have more to do with the `@new` value?

Comment: Testing the edits with namespace-qualified elements that use namespace-prefixes, it works. And if you specify the same namespace-prefix for the `@new` value such as `<convert old="Fees" new="x:Fee"/>` it generated output with that namespace-prefix and the namespace of the originally matched element.

Comment: Sure, if `@new` had a prefix you'd get a prefix.  But if (as in UBL) I have two elements with the same local name in two different namespaces, there would be a problem.  And if one is dealing in namespaces, you'd have to prefix *every* `@new` if you didn't want to use the default namespace.  And if there are attributes using the namespace, they need a prefix.  All I'm saying is I think preserving the prefixed name is safest, and a true namespace-aware solution would have to be prefix-independent.

Comment: If the matched element uses a namespace prefix and the `@old` does not (or has a different prefix value), it will not match when looking up the key with `name()`, right?

Comment: Yes it will not work, and if the matched element uses a namespace prefix that is different than the namespace prefix used in the `@old` it also will not work.  Working with prefixes is just too fragile.  A truly general result would have old and new namespace URI strings as values available in `<convert>`, match on `local-name()` and the namespace URI, then create the element with `@new` (and its prefix) and, possibly, a new URI if changing the vocabulary would also be desired (but not in this case of a simple rename).

Comment: Hi Ken, can we do the above solution in XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 1):

You don't show what you have already tried.  Once again we don't know if you are asking us for guidance or if you are asking us to do your work for you.

The example below makes the following assumptions regarding plurals, if you have any more then it is up to you:

- "ies" -> "y"
- "s" -> ""

It would have helped if you enumerated all of the "plural to single" rules you want to accommodate.  For example, if you have an element named `<Class>` then the stylesheet below will corrupt that to be `<Clas>`.  The concept of "plural" in spelling is not very straightforward at all.  I suggest you use a look-up table and enumerate the changes you want.

Again, your question is incomplete and you impose extra time on volunteers to help.

```
t:\ftemp>type plural.xml 
<ExternalAssessmentRequest>
    <ApplicationData Lender="MegaBank">
        <LiabilityList>
            <RequestedLoans>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
                <Features Code="Test"/>
            </RequestedLoans>
            <ExistingLoans>
                <Securities RelatedIdentifier="Test"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </ExistingLoans>
            <OtherLiabilities >
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </OtherLiabilities>
            <Expenses Amount="50" Description="Train Ticket" Identifier="Expense1" NonRecurring="Yes" Type="Transport" Year="2013">
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </Expenses>
        </LiabilityList>
        <AssetList>
            <Assets >
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </Assets>
            <Funds Amount="1000" Description="Slush Fund" Identifier="Fund1"/>
        </AssetList>
        <IncomeList>
            <Incomes >
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicants Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </Incomes>
        </IncomeList>
        <ApplicantList>
            <Households AdditionalAdults="0" Boarding="Yes" Children="0" Description="1 Test St, Sydney" Postcode="2000">
                <Persons CountryOfResidence="Australia" CustomerDurationInMonths="0" DischargedBankrupts="0" Identifier="Applicant1" Name="John Smith" Partner="Applicant2" Partnered="Yes" PermanentResident="Yes"/>
                <Persons CountryOfResidence="Australia" CustomerDurationInMonths="0" DischargedBankrupts="0" Identifier="Applicant2" Name="Jane Smith" Partner="Applicant1" Partnered="Yes" PermanentResident="Yes"/>
                <Guarantors/>
            </Households>
            <Companies Identifier="Company1" Name="Tardis">
                <Directors RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
            </Companies>
        </ApplicantList>
        <FeeList>
            <Fees Amount="100" Capitalised="Yes" DateOfPayment="1967-08-13" Description="Application Fee" Identifier="Fee1" PaidAmount="0"/>
        </FeeList>
    </ApplicationData>
    <AdditionalAssessments Lender="MegaBank">
        <RequestedLoans Product="Supa Variable" ProductID="Product2"/>
    </AdditionalAssessments>
</ExternalAssessmentRequest>
t:\ftemp>call xslt2 plural.xml plural.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ExternalAssessmentRequest>
    <ApplicationData Lender="MegaBank">
        <LiabilityList>
            <RequestedLoan>
                <Applicant Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicant Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
                <Feature Code="Test"/>
            </RequestedLoan>
            <ExistingLoan>
                <Security RelatedIdentifier="Test"/>
                <Applicant Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicant Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </ExistingLoan>
            <OtherLiability>
                <Applicant Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicant Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </OtherLiability>
            <Expense Amount="50" Description="Train Ticket" Identifier="Expense1" NonRecurring="Yes" Type="Transport" Year="2013">
                <Applicant Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicant Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </Expense>
        </LiabilityList>
        <AssetList>
            <Asset>
                <Applicant Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicant Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </Asset>
            <Fund Amount="1000" Description="Slush Fund" Identifier="Fund1"/>
        </AssetList>
        <IncomeList>
            <Income>
                <Applicant Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
                <Applicant Percentage="0.5" RelatedIdentifier="Applicant2"/>
            </Income>
        </IncomeList>
        <ApplicantList>
            <Household AdditionalAdults="0" Boarding="Yes" Children="0" Description="1 Test St, Sydney" Postcode="2000">
                <Person CountryOfResidence="Australia" CustomerDurationInMonths="0" DischargedBankrupts="0" Identifier="Applicant1" Name="John Smith" Partner="Applicant2" Partnered="Yes" PermanentResident="Yes"/>
                <Person CountryOfResidence="Australia" CustomerDurationInMonths="0" DischargedBankrupts="0" Identifier="Applicant2" Name="Jane Smith" Partner="Applicant1" Partnered="Yes" PermanentResident="Yes"/>
                <Guarantor/>
            </Household>
            <Company Identifier="Company1" Name="Tardis">
                <Director RelatedIdentifier="Applicant1"/>
            </Company>
        </ApplicantList>
        <FeeList>
            <Fee Amount="100" Capitalised="Yes" DateOfPayment="1967-08-13" Description="Application Fee" Identifier="Fee1" PaidAmount="0"/>
        </FeeList>
    </ApplicationData>
    <AdditionalAssessment Lender="MegaBank">
        <RequestedLoan Product="Supa Variable" ProductID="Product2"/>
    </AdditionalAssessment>
</ExternalAssessmentRequest>
t:\ftemp>type plural.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsd"
                version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="*[ends-with(name(.),'ies')]" priority="1">
  <xsl:element name="{substring(name(.),1,string-length(name(.))-3)}y">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*,node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[ends-with(name(.),'s')]">
  <xsl:element name="{substring(name(.),1,string-length(name(.))-1)}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*,node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()"><!--identity for all other nodes-->
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*,node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
t:\ftemp>rem Done!
```

Comment: Dear Ken, thanks again for your answer. I don not have any knowledge of xsl and I have been asked to do this task in a small amount of time.

Comment: I have a schema which I have to validate the output of the xml against. How can I use a look-up table to enumerate the changes.

Comment: Is it better to check each element one by one?

Comment: Im getting the data in JSON format and Im converting it to XML, the JSON format has bunch of array object which have plural names. But in the xml schema that I have to validate the converted JSON to xml the element's names are singular

Comment: Yes, it is better to check each element one by one, which is why I posted the solution with the look-up table.

Comment: Okay, so if you "don't have any knowledge of XSL" as you say, then you should be asking in your posts for people to give you complete solutions, not asking for advice.  Then volunteers know that they are doing your work for you, rather than trying to advise you.

Answer (score 0):

A very generic XSLT 1.0 solution that looks for elements that end with `s` `es` and `ies` and generates the singular version of the element name by removing `s` and `es` and replacing `ies` with `y`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[substring(local-name(), 
                                 string-length(local-name())) = 's']">   
    <xsl:element name="{substring(name(), 0, string-length(name()))}" 
                 namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[substring(local-name(), 
                                 string-length(local-name())-1) = 'es']" 
              priority="1">
    <xsl:element name="{substring(name(), 0, string-length(name()))}" 
                 namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[substring(local-name(), 
                                 string-length(local-name())-2) = 'ies']" 
              priority="2">
    <xsl:element name="{substring(name(), 0, string-length(name())-2)}y" 
                 namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A more specific stylesheet would specify each of the element names that you would want to change, using the `|` union operator to match any of them and apply the logic specified in the matching template to remove/change the ending of the element name:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="RequestedLoans | Applicants | Assets | Funds | 
                           Households | Persons | Guarantors | Directors">   
    <xsl:element name="{substring(name(), 0, string-length(name()))}" 
                 namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Incomes | Expenses | Features" priority="1">
    <xsl:element name="{substring(name(), 0, string-length(name()))}" 
                 namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Companies" priority="2">
    <xsl:element name="{substring(name(), 0, string-length(name())-2)}y" 
                 namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```